# Configuring uv4L for webRTC using USB camera on RPI2 raspbian

Tags: usb, camera, pi-2, uv4l, webrtc

To make a UV4L WebRTC client for [KMS](http://www.kurento.org), i am trying to run a USB camera on RPI2 with the UV4L driver, I Tried with the Microsoft lifeCam, which is UVC compliant. [Tutorials](http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/sections/index.php?op=viewarticle&artid=14) only show this working with raspicam, so I'm also sharing my findings.

I installed following packages :

`sudo apt-get install uv4l uv4l-server uv4l-uvc uv4l-server uv4l-webrtc uv4l-xmpp-bridge`

Here is the `dmesg` output on camera plug :

```
[60766.138060] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 8 using dwc_otg
[60766.272514] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=0772
[60766.272561] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[60766.272578] usb 1-1.4: Product: Microsoft\xffffffc2\xffffffae\xffffffae LifeCam Studio(TM)
[60766.272594] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: Microsoft
[60766.275111] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Microsoft\xffffffc2\xffffffae\xffffffae LifeCam Studio(TM) (045e:0772)
[60766.275130] uvcvideo: Forcing device quirks to 0x80 by module parameter for testing purpose.
[60766.275141] uvcvideo: Please report required quirks to the linux-uvc-devel mailing list.
[60766.334638] input: Microsoft\xffffffc2\xffffffae\xffffffae LifeCam Studio(TM) as /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/input/input3
[60766.702641] hid-generic 0003:045E:0772.0003: hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.01 Device [Microsoft Microsoft\xffffffc2\xffffffae\xffffffae LifeCam Studio(TM)] on usb-3f980000.usb-1.4/input4
```

and then invoque uv4l :

```
uv4l --syslog-host localhost --driver uvc --device-id 045e:0772

<notice> [core] Trying driver 'uvc' from built-in drivers...
<warning> [core] Driver 'uvc' not found
<notice> [core] Trying driver 'uvc' from external plug-in's...
<notice> [driver] Video functionality 'Microsoft? LifeCam Studio(TM)' recognized at 045e:0772
<notice> [core] Device detected!
<notice> [core] Registering device node /dev/uv4l
```

I Changed one config file line : `sudo vim /etc/uv4l/uv4l-raspicam.conf`

```
driver = uvc
```

Now I can connect to `http://builtinfab.local:8080/stream/webrtc` and see the video display (great).

I would like to go further in configuration, especially being able to tune XMPP parameters, BUT seems like changes have no effect when editing `/etc/uv4l/uv4l-raspicam.conf`, even after killing `sudo pkill uv4l` & restart.

Someone has any idea about that ? Should I create another config file or rename it ?

EDIT : **I found it.**
Just needed to add i.e. `--config-file=/etc/uv4l/uv4l-uvc.conf` to the uv4l command.

Comment: You can post your finding as an answer and accept it so that it helps others having the same problem.

Comment: @dastaan: Also worth noting, it will give the OP a rep boost to do so ;)

Comment: I tried installing the packages on a pi 3B running 4.4.26-v7+ #915 and it produced errors "E: Unable to location package *" where * is every package listed in the original post.  What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it. Just needed to add i.e. --config-file=/etc/uv4l/uv4l-uvc.conf to the uv4l command, you will have to create the config file first.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks, JP. I followed your instructions and got my Logitech cam streaming successfully.
Just the following notes for anyone interested, based on my experience:

- Did not need uv4l-xmpp-bridge (at least for basic streaming)
- uvc driver configuration file defaults streaming to port 8090 (not 8080 as in your example).
- Needed a powered USB hub to get my camera running (in case someone runs into the same problem).
- uv4l loads cpu to ~12% when streaming (just saying).

I am using a RPI 2, Raspbian Jessie, uv4l 1.9.11.